# Javascript; Using createElement to load data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

The problem im having is finding out a way when data is loaded that it will create its own Elements the way i have it set for when clicking on "Rasie New Pokemon".

```
function newPokemon() {
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
// Creates a new div
var xpPar = document.createElement("p");
var lvlPar = document.createElement("p");
var nxtLvlPar = document.createElement("p");
var namePar = document.createElement("p");
// Creates a new paragraph element

var newImg = document.createElement("img");
// Creates a new image element

var pokemon = ["Mudkip", "Treecko", "Torchic"];
// Array containing pokemon that can be raised

var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
// Chooses a randome number between 1 and 2

if (numOfPoke < 1) {

    newDiv.id = "content";

    newImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
    newImg.id= "pokemon";

    switch (randNum) {
        case 0:
            newImg.src = "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/258.gif";
        break;
        case 1:
            newImg.src = "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/252.gif";
        break;
        case 2:
            newImg.src = "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/255.gif";
        break;
        default:
            alert("Something went wrong! Alert the creator of the game!");
        break;
    }

    newImg.onclick = function() {
        addXP()
    };

    xpPar.id = "xp";
    xpPar.innerHTML = "XP: " + xp.toFixed();

    lvlPar.id = "lvl";
    lvlPar.innerHTML = "Level: " + lvl;

    nxtLvlPar.id = "nxt_lvl";
    nxtLvlPar.innerHTML = "XP To Next Level: " + xpToNxtLvl.toFixed(2);

    namePar.id = "name";
    namePar.innerHTML = pokemon[randNum];

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newImg);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(xpPar);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(lvlPar);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(namePar);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(nxtLvlPar);

    numOfPoke++;
    // Adds one to the pokemon counter
} else {
    alert("Only one Pokemon can be raised at a time!");
}
// Allows only one new pokemon to be raised
}
```

This is the function i am using to create the elements. What i want is for when the data is loaded it will create the data in a smiler way.

here is a link to my [files.[1]](http://www.zeroprox.tk/PokemonGame.zip) I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle for some reason.

Comment: Oooooooo no jQuery! You are brave.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 or, like me, he's just too scared to use jQuery. Also @Zer0Pr0x you can't store an element in `localStorage` (as you've probably discovered), but you can store the information and then populate an element with it

Comment: @Markasoftware - Why would one be scared to use jQuery?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 i don't know, I'm just kind've kidding. I don't like it because (like all JavaScript libraries) isn't essential for anything; everything it does can be emulated with pure JS and since it doesn't do any reallly hard to do stuff, I don't want it. I use libraries for things like unzipping `.zip` files (something I don't know how to do and is pretty difficult, i think), but jQuery...I don't see the point

Comment: @Markasoftware - I was trying to not use jQuery too at one point. I tried, and the code was starting to get extremely messy. I couldn't chain methods, and had to use `for` every single time to loop through an array... ahh those time had passes and jQuery... is so *amazing* that simply no one can assist! (okay that's a bit exaggerated but whatever :P) Just think of how you can add CSS styles without jQuery! >_<

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 this is getting REALLY off-topic, so I'm going to post this as the last thing here. First off, jQuery is stupid. Second off, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `for` loops (such as `someArray.forEach(function(curValue){alert(curValue);});` or `[].forEach.call(someArray,function(curValue){alert(curValue);});` and also, your website is down because of too much CPU usage. And I know somebody's going to mark this as too chatty

Comment: @Markasoftware - *What the* too much CPU usage Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: Im just playing around with what i learned in my intro to JavaScript class that i just finished up last semester. Unfortunately we didn't learn jQuery but i definitely plan on learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving it into local storage and getting people mad when they clear their cache how about storing it on a server ? And Create a php array on that server containing the data of your pokemon ?

```
var currentPokemon;

var Pokemon = {

    0: {
        Name: "Mudkip",
        Exp: 0,
        NextExp: 50,
        Lvl: 1, 
        Img: "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/258.gif"
    },

    1: {
        Name: "Treecko",
        Exp: 0,
        NextExp: 50,
        Lvl: 1, 
        Img: "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/252.gif"
    },

    2: {
        Name: "Torchic",
        Exp: 0,
        NextExp: 50,
        Lvl: 1, 
        Img: "http://www.pokestadium.com/pokemon/sprites/img/main-series/5/black-white/animated/front/255.gif"
    }

};

currentPokemon = Pokemon[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

/*
    Now you can get all data you want from currentPokemon :)
*/
```

Comment: So basically this is an Array.

Comment: Er anything wrong with that ? Oh damn diden't see local storage my bad

Comment: Because `[a, b]` is the same as `{0: a, 1: b}`.

Comment: I like being explicit :p

Comment: I plan on using PHP in the future. This semester i will be taking a php/mysql course so i'm really excited for that! My goal here is just to play around with what i know about JavaScript from my class that i just finished up. The reason i went with localStorage was because that's the only way that i could think of to save the data with JavaScript unless there is another way?

Comment: My goal with my code is to find a way to have the load data display the same way that i used with the newPokemon() function. Im have troubles with the load and saving with localStorage. This game is just something that i am putting together to test my JavaScript Skills that i have learned so far.